# Bulk/batch select and insert in php

Tags: php, sql, db2, odbc

I have a script that runs a select on DB2 and then inserts into a database.

This works perfectly but there's one problem: I have 500,000 records that are involved and I need to find a non-exhaustive way to do this. Currently, I've been running it in powershell but my script has the select query limited to 1000 at a time and it will take forever.

I'm hoping I can modify this slightly to avoid any errors or timeouts/memory issues and maybe select the first 500, insert, then start over, if that makes sense.

I know there's array_chunk too but I've never used it so I'm not sure how to go about it. What's the best way I can preform this until the select is empty essentially?

The script portion:

```
//DB2 Select query
$plcQueryDB2 = " 

        select  
            cstnoc AS DEALER,
            framec AS FRAME,
            covr1c AS COVER,
            colr1c AS COLOR ,
            extd1d AS SHIPDATE,
            orqtyc AS QUANTITY
        FROM GPORPCFL
        group by invnoc,cstnoc, slsnoc, orqtyc, framec, covr1c,colr1c, extd1d
        order by invnoc asc
        limit 200
";

var_dump ($plcQueryDB2);

//prepare and execute on db2
$prep = odbc_prepare($DB2Conn, $plcQueryDB2);
$exec = odbc_execute($prep);
$result = odbc_exec($DB2Conn, $plcQueryDB2);


try{

    while($arr = odbc_fetch_array($result)) 
    {

        $stmt = $PDO->prepare("
            INSERT INTO placements (sku_id, group_id, dealer_id, start_date, expire_date,locations)
            SELECT id, sku_group_id, :DEALER, DATE_ADD(DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT(:SHIPDATE, CHAR(20)), '%Y-%m-%d'),INTERVAL 27 DAY) as start_date,
            DATE_ADD(DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT(:SHIPDATE, CHAR(20)), '%Y-%m-%d'),INTERVAL 127 DAY) as expire_date, :QUANTITY  
            FROM skus s
            WHERE  s.frame=:FRAME AND s.cover1=:COVER AND s.color1=:COLOR
        ");

        $PDO->beginTransaction();
        $i = 0;
        while($db2row = odbc_fetch_array($result)) {

            if(++$i % 1000 == 0) {
                $PDO->commit();
                $PDO->beginTransaction();
            }

            $stmt->execute($db2row);

        }
        $PDO->commit();
    }
}catch (PDOException $e){
    print "ERROR!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
```

Comment: `odbc_*` isn't mysql

Comment: Correct, i just fixed the tags for that. I added the mysql for the insert portion but I just added db2 and odbc as tags. Thanks